# Custom columns in fullcalendar list view

Tags: fullcalendar

I'd like to add more columns to my list day view. So far the only way I have found to achieve this is by manually adding columns in the eventRender function.

Like so:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultView: 'listDay',  
  eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
    element.find(".fc-list-item-time").after("<td>Extra column 1 here</td>");
    element.find(".fc-list-item-time").after("<td>Extra column 2 here</td>");
    element.find(".fc-list-item-time").after("<td>Etc</td>");
  }
});
```

Is there a better way of achieving more columns?

(I did find the relevant feature request on [github](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3422) and upvoted it.)

Answer (score 0):

i would do that in the [viewRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/viewRender) function.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultView: 'listDay',  
  viewRender: function (view, element) {
    element.find(".fc-list-item-time").after("<td>Extra column 1 here</td>");
    element.find(".fc-list-item-time").after("<td>Extra column 2 here</td>");
    element.find(".fc-list-item-time").after("<td>Etc</td>");
  }
});
```

**Edit**:
If you want to have dynamic cols content for each event you have to use eventRender to add the cols

adding more cols will break the row with the header, because this is set to a fixed colspan. you can add cols in eventRender and then in viewRender, count those cols and set the colspan of the header row to that.

```
  viewRender: function(view, element){
   var cols = element.find('.fc-list-item')[0].children.length;

   $.each(element.find('.fc-widget-header'),function(){ 
    $(this).attr('colspan',cols);
   });

}
```

Comment: The viewRender function is only called once for the view right? So how will I then populate my column data for all the events (the rows on the table)?

Comment: yes, that's true. Because you added static html in your example i didn't realize that you probably want to fill the cols with event data. When testing this, adding cols to the event would break the row containing the header. I updated my answer with a fix for this inside the viewRender function

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion about the column headers. But this still leaves me with adding columns manually in the eventRender and viewRender functions. I'm wondering if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I tried to add a column. It goes. But add a column to `.fc-widget-header` add in the same way `element.find('.fc-widget-header').after('<td class=\"fc-widget-header\" colspan=\"1\"></td>');` it is not.